# Get largest Subset of Integers with certain minimum distance/difference

Tags: algorithm

i have a Set of Integers or example: {1,3,4,5,10} now i want the biggest (biggest = most elements) Subset where each element has a minimum distance/difference to each other element.

For example with the Set {1,3,4,5,10} and minimum distance 2 a result could be:

{1,3,5,10}

or for distance 3:

{1,5,10}

Does a (good/efficient) algorithm exist to solve that problem ?

Comment: By distance do you mean difference?

Comment: This is easily reducible to the independent set problem. Unfortunately that's NP-complete so that doesn't really get you anywhere...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subset of Set of Dates thats maximal and with certain distance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850812/subset-of-set-of-dates-thats-maximal-and-with-certain-distance)

Comment: i duplicated because i was told to reask the question with integers instead of dates. The old post can be removed.

Comment: @NickRussler, there is no difference in my solution by integers or dates, also date basically is just a `int64` in most languages, in all the algorithm wont change and you can simply find this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely not a NP-complete problem.

Actually it is a special case of the classic [Interval Scheduling](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne/kleinberg-tardos/04greedy-2x2.pdf) problem, while in normal Interval Scheduling problem, the length is not fixed

Here in your problem, you can view each number is the start time of an interval, and each interval have your "minimum distance" as the interval length.

Each interval has a finish time, which is start time + interval length

So the solution would be

1 Sort all the interval by finish time.

2 Go through them in the sorted order one by one, add the interval to the result set which is compatible with all existing intervals in the result set.

This solution is optimal and have O(nlogn) time complexity.

You can find the proof and info about other greedy algorithm in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines:

1) Sort the input.

2) Go through the input and mark each element with the number of elements they would exclude from the set if they were chose.

3) Pick from the available elements, in order, the ones with the lowest mark.

4) Remove the excluded elements.

5) Repeat 3) and 4)

So, on your example:

```
1  3  4  5  10     - difference 3
```

Step 1 is already done, going to step 2 we get:

```
1  3  4  5  10
1  3  2  2  0
```

Explanation - if we pick `1`, we exclude 1 number -3; if we pick `3`, we exclude 3 numbers -1,4 and 5, and so on...

Next steps:

- Pick 10, remove nothing. - `1 3 4 5 (10)`
- Pick 1, remove 3.        - `(1) 4 5 (10)`
- Pick 4 (or 5), remove 5 (or 4) - `1 4 10`

I don't guarantee this works, but it's a start...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the following greedy algorithm gives optimal solutions. Scan through the integers in sorted order, taking each integer if the previous integer taken is sufficiently far. Correctness follows by an induction proof that, for every solution S and every integer u, the greedy solution chooses at least as many integers ≤ u as S.